# Open Finder in list view from command line

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line

I know that I can open Finder for a certain directory from the command line by using

```
open DIRECTORYPATH
```

This shows the directory in the default view, which is fine most of the time. However I sometimes want to show the directory in *list view*, without changing the default `Finder` settings; the list view should only apply to this particular Finder instance. Is this possible?

From the man-page for `open`, I see that there is an option `--args`, which is used to pass options through to the application which is eventually invoked by `open`. I guess that if I have the chance to pass the request to display the directory in list view, it must be through this --args. However I have not found what kind of arguments finder would accept.